# How can I flatten a dictionary of dictionaries and sum the values of the inner dictionary with LINQ?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have the following object:

```
countDictionary As Dictionary(of Category, Dictionary(of Date, Integer))
```

The `Class` has a Enumeration Property. For the purposes of demonstration, I'll call it `MasterCategory`.

I have been trying to get out an object that looks like the following:

```
groupedCountDictionary As Dictionary(of MasterCategory, Dictionary(of Date, Integer)
```

The best result I could get was:

```
Lookup(of MasterCategory, Dictionary(of Date, Integer))
```

From:

```
countDictionary.ToLookup(Function(o) o.Key.MasterCategory, Function(o) o.Value)
```

Which results in a `IEnumerable (Of Dictionary(of Date, Integer))` for each `MasterCategory` value.

However, I need that IEnumerable of Dictionary **flattened to one dictionary with all the integers summed** (total counts) for each date.

I then tried to use various `select`s and `group by`s (from numerous stackoverflow posts) to "flatten" it, but my efforts have fallen short.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this? Looking for *VB.Net* answers if possible.

**Edit:**

**Current Code**

```
[Category Class]
-    MasterCategory As Enum
-    Name As String etc

[countDictionary As Dictionary(of Category Objects, Dictionary(of Date, Integer))]
-    length 8
-    Children of 8 Categories:
        3 with MasterCategory A, 1097 int's by date
        4 with MasterCategory B, 1097 int's by date
        1 with MasterCategory C, 1097 int's by date
```

**Best Effort**

```
[Lookup(of MasterCategory, Dictionary(of Date, Integer)]
-    length 3
-    Children of 3 Master Categories:
     1 of IEnumerable(of Dictionary(of Date, Integer)) and length 3
         3 x Dictionary length 1097 int's by date

     1 of IEnumerable(of Dictionary(of Date, Integer)) and length 4
         3 x Dictionary length 1097 int's by date

     1 of IEnumerable(of Dictionary(of Date, Integer)) and length 1
         3 x Dictionary length 1097 int's by date
```

**Required**

```
[Dictionary(MasterCategory, Dictionary(of Date, Integer))]
-    length 3
-    Children of 3 Master Categories:
     3 of Dictionary(of Date, Integer) with summed total int's
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you after `SelectMany`? If so this might do what you're after:

C#

```
test.SelectMany(x => x.Key.MasterCategory).Sum(x => x.ThePropertyToSum)
```

Which in VB, I think is:

```
test.SelectMany(Function(x) x.Key.MasterCategory).Sum(Function(x) x.ThePropertyToSum)
```

Comment: Thanks - I have tried this above as you've written it, but get an Overload resolution failed message (no accessible "SelectMany" can be called with these arguments). I can't test the Sum yet as the select many errors. Am I missing something?

This is the full error: http://pastebin.com/pZizyyuy

Comment: Can you update your question with a stripped down, but complete object structure? It might be that I've miss-understood your question.

Comment: Have updated with example objects. Sorry, I should have done that originally! :)